# Python: Converting to str while keeping leading 0's

Tags: python

So in python I'm trying to access a file path in the order of 000X

So I start by setting a string to

```
path = '0001'
```

and then point to and open the file path

```
filepath = open('/home/pi/Pictures' + path + '.JPG', 'rb')
```

so I do my business and now want to access the next file of extension 0002

```
intpath = int(path)
intpath = intpath + 1
path = str(intpath)
```

I'm sure this is inefficient, but I'm starting out. Unfortunately, this makes path '2' and not '0002'....any idea how I can maintain the leading zeros?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this

```
>>> ['{0:04}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 15)]
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', 
 '0010', '0011', '0012', '0013', '0014']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you need 4 digits, use string formatting:

```
path = "%04d" % (intpath+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use one of the others, but for completeness, there's also `zfill`:

```
'1'.zfill(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage of `str.format` is that it's easy to parameterise the width. If your Python is 2.5 or older you'll have to use the `%` formatting

```
>>> ['{i:0{width}}'.format(i=i, width=4) for i in range(1, 15)]
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', '0010', '0011', '0012', '0013', '0014']
```